# Styling the MultiBinding TextBlock in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, multibinding

I'm trying to Bold only one of the TextBlocks in multibinding.

The Multibinding code is,

```
<TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="2 0 0 0">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}">
            <Binding Path="Value" Mode="OneWay"/>
            <Binding Path="Status" Mode="OneWay" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

In the above block, I want to bold the second binding alone. Something like this

`<Binding Path="Status" Mode="OneWay" FontWeight="Bold"/>`

But there is no FontWeight property for the Binding Control.

Is there any other property to add style to the Binding tag?
or 
Is there any other way that I can add style only to a particular TextBlock in MultiBinding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding isn't a control and **can not** have a Style

for TextBlock you can declare `Inlines`

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="2 0 0 0">
    <Run Text="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Status, Mode=OneWay}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
</TextBlock>
```